# Can you explain the following definition in layman's terms?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

Probability $P_X$ on the space $(\Bbb R^n, \mathcal B_n)$ defined in the following way:

$\forall B \in \mathcal B_n : P_X(B) = P(X^{-1}(B))$

is called the **Distribution** of a random variable $X$.

Comment: The definition is incomplete as you need a probability $P$ defined on the space $\Omega$ on which $X$ is defined;$$X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$$

Comment: Banach spaces in layman terms? Can you describe your image of a layman in this case?

Comment: @Aksakal, just translate the definition into simple English.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathcal{B}_n$ is apparently some $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and so $B$ is a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  The probability that $X$ belongs to this set is the probability that we draw an $\omega \in \Omega$ that maps to $B$ under the function $X$, i.e., $X(\omega) \in B$.  The collection of all such points is $X^{-1}(B)$ and the probability of this collection is $P(X^{-1}(B))$.

Answer (score 0):

You describe all the events that may happen. Then attach real numbers to non-overlapping sets of events. You already have the probabilities attached to events and sets of events. So, you should be able to track the probability of the real number by first finding the events to which it's attached, then finding the probability of these events. That is the probability distribution, i.e. mapping of real numbers to probabilities.

To a layman, this whole events and Banach business is behind the curtains. All the layman sees is the final mapping of real numbers (random variable realizations) to probabilities. This works the same way for continuous and discrete distribution, though the latter is often easier to explain to a total dummy since you can do this with coin flip examples or similar trivial exercises.

Comment: I am unable to understand what this answer is trying to say or how it is an answer to the question being asked. Has Aksakal's account been hacked and the answer is spam written by the hacker? What on earth is "the probability of the real number"? What is the probability attached to $1.2345$ and how does if differ from the probability attached to $9.8765$?